# PDF document generating, Letter 'N' become 'ᴉ' (i upside down) when viewing in safari ios 16

Tags: php, laravel-9, laravel-dompdf

I have a problem with letter generating the letter 'N' become become 'ᴉ' (i upside down). I am working Laravel 9 using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf. In pc it is okay but when I open in my iphone (ios 16) I got this problem.

In My controller

```
public function recreate_card(Student $student){
    $students[] = $student;
    // return view('templates/student-card', compact('students'));
        
    $pdf = Pdf::loadView('templates/student-card', compact('students'));
    return $pdf->stream('student_card.pdf');
}
```

HTML Template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{{ __('Student Card') }}</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            html {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                line-height: 1;
                margin: 15mm;
                font-size: 1mm;
                /* overflow: hidden; */
            }

            body {
                font-family: "Arial (sans-serif)";
                font-weight: 400;
                line-height: 1.5;
                color: #212529;
                text-align: left;
                background-color: #fff;
                font-size: 3mm;
                padding-top: 15mm;
            }
...
<td class="fw-bold" colspan="2" style="text-align: center; font-size: 3.5mm; color: #014669;">{{ strtoupper($student->first_name).' '.strtoupper($student->last_name) }}</td>
...
```

Result that I got:
[image]

**My Expectation**: Supposed to be '**BO MATIN**'

Comment: **In pc it is okay** but when I open in my iphone (ios 16) I got this problem -- so this problem only happens in your ios / iphone ??

Comment: Yes the problem only happen with iOS 16.

Comment: I found the solution. I change font-family in body from  font-family: "Arial (sans-serif)"; to font-family: Arial, sans-serif;

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I change font-family in **body** from  `font-family: "Arial (sans-serif)";` to `font-family: Arial, sans-serif;`